# OpenGL lighting vector normalization

Tags: c, opengl, lighting

I am attempting to find the vector normalization for an arbitrary object loaded into an opengl program. I am trying to calculate the normals for all the vertices. What I have gathered is that I need to first calculate the normals for the faces, then find the average of the normals for the vertices.

When I run the program some of the object is lit correctly, but for the most part it is not. The triangles on each independent face seems to be lit correctly, but not the adjacent face. To calculate the normal of each vertex I would assume that I would have the find the normalized average of the six connecting triangles, attempting to do so did not seem to work.

Here is the code I am using for trying to calculate the normals of each face.

```
vec3 one, two;
for(int i = 0; i < vertices.vertexNumber; i += 3)
{
    one.x = point3[i+1].x - point3[i].x;
    one.y = point3[i+1].y - point3[i].y;
    one.z = point3[i+1].z - point3[i].z;

    two.x = point3[i+2].x - point3[i].x;
    two.y = point3[i+2].y - point3[i].y;
    two.z = point3[i+2].z - point3[i].z;

    vec3 normal = normalizevec3(crossvec3(one, two));

    normalized[i] = normal;
}
```

and the function I am using to normalize the vectors

```
vec3 normalizevec3(vec3 v) {
float vecLength = lengthvec3(v);
vec3 dividebyzero = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
if (vecLength == 0)
    return dividebyzero;
float X, Y, Z;
X = v.x / vecLength;
Y = v.y / vecLength;
Z = v.z / vecLength;
vec3 u = {X, Y, Z};
return u;
}
```

After some refactoring some here is what my cube looks like.

[image]

[image]

The normal values I am getting are

```
0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
-1.000000, 0.000000, -0.000000
-1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
-1.000000, 0.000000, -0.000000
-1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000
-0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000
0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000
-0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000
```

Comment: If you're trying to generate normals for an arbitrary mesh (which doesn't already have normals), you'll need a cross-product in there, and some way to share the same vertex between multiple triangles (unless your meshes never use a vertex twice) - each triangle will have a different normal, but you must specify it on a per-vertex basis

Answer (score -1):

The normal for a triangle is given by the order of vertices.

What you are doing there is wrong, because you are substracting directions and then using cross product to obtain a perpendicular direction, which is just nonsense  (you can substract two POINTS and get a vector out of that, and then normalize it to a direction, but two directions make no sense to substract them).

If you want to find the average normal of a Triangle (considering that the triangle has different normals for each vector) use a raw average then normalize. It will work fine.

You seem to already have the normal information (normals vector). That's sufficient for lightning !

The only time you need to compute a vertex "normal" is when you actually compute it's tangent and binormal in order to apply Normal Maps. First implement correctly the Phong shader then you can go to Normal Maps .